Проблемы с reCAPTCHA от Google
есть сайт на Wordpress, формf создавались с помощью плагина Gravity Forms. Форма работают отлично. Но только форма возращает ошибку The reCAPTCHA was invalid. Go back and try it again. Я перепробовал все что можно, поменял ключи для капчи.
В чем может быть проблема и как ее решить?

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! Мы заметили, что ваш вопрос требует некоторых уточнений. Прежде чем его опубликовать, рекомендуем ознакомиться с справкой о том, как задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Откройте консоль разработчика в вашем браузере (обычно это можно сделать с помощью клавиши F12 или Ctrl+Shift+I) и посмотрите на ошибки. Они могут дать подсказки о том, в чем проблема

В режиме инкогнито браузеры часто блокируют сторонние cookies и другие трекеры. Это может нарушить работу reCAPTCHA (Попробуйте использовать режим инкогнито в другом браузере, чтобы исключить проблему конкретного браузера.)

ERROR for site owner: Invalid site key

А выкинуть говнокапчи и использовать нормальные методы защиты от спама - не вариант?

@SeVlad нормальные это какие?

@andreymal вариантов море. Тут перечислена  малая часть методов. Для ВП есть готовые плагины с этими методами.

Нужно было просто подождать. Зашел на сайт на следующий день, почистил кэш и все заработало.
ИЛИ ЖЕ НАДО БЫЛО ОБНОВИТЬ КЭШ НА СЕРВЕРЕ.
